# How to move two divs upqwards in the dom using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I an not sure how to do this.
I have the following code:

```
<div class="one">You might also invite...</div>
<div class="pic1"></div>
<div class="name1">Some name</div>
<div class="pic2"></div>
<div class="name2">Another Name</div>
<div class="pic3"></div>
<div class="name3">Third Name</div>
```

Now, what I want is, that one some event, I want the divs with class pic2 and name2 to jump to another position in the code, like this:

```
<div class="pic2"></div>
<div class="name2">Another Name</div>
<div class="one">You might also invite...</div>
<div class="pic1"></div>
<div class="name1">Some name</div>
<div class="pic3"></div>
<div class="name3">Third Name</div>
```

How should this be achieved?
Should I be using something like "prepend"? or I would have to recurse through the dom and reposition them...

Thanks

Comment: How are you determining the new position? Just by ID? `detach()` and `prependTo()` are probably going to do the job.

Comment: I just want them to move above the div with class "one"

Comment: A bit off topic, but since they're classes (not unique). Why do you have a separate name for each of them? I mean couldn't you select them with `document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0]` with the identifier `[0]`? If not, they should be IDs instead (just my personal opinion, I find it kinda bad practice to use classes with a unique mannor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/fyL324oz/)***

You would use [insertBefore()<sup>jQuery API</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

```
$('.pic2').insertBefore('.one');
$('.name2').insertBefore('.one');
```

Comment: Or combine the selectors into a single statement. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fyL324oz/1/

Comment: @isherwood - I was unsure if jQuery would always properly order the list of selectors. For example, if `'.pic2, name2'` were the selector, would it always be the case `pic2` was inserted first? Would some complex selectors change the order? So I separated them here.

Comment: Thanks, the "insertBefore" solved it :) I made a small error in my code above, actually not everything is unique. The names are all having same class name whereas pictures have different ones. So for sure I can have ID's for pictures but names I want to keep them as class.

Comment: So when I was tried insertbefore one after other, there was a problem because the name was a class name and many other elements had same class, so selecting it was a problem. I thought I could use the jsfiddle example of combining the selectors in one, but I have to select like this - first select $('.pic2') then select $('.pic2').next().... this didnt work in the jsfiddle example (obviously I am not doing in the right way.... will keep trying though

Comment: @ssdesign - Yeah there was only the one class in your example. If you have a more complex situation you can reproduce in a jsfiddle, I will try to help you with the selector for that.